# Programmatic way to Build Model by Variable Significance from Bivariate Regressions

Tags: python, pandas, regression

So I can build out bivariate models regression “opportunity score” on each individual variable in Spreg using the following code.

````
```
from pysal.model import spreg

variable_names = [
    'crime_count',
    'bus_count',
    'median_hh_', 
    'population', 
    'per_white',
    'per_black',
    'per_asian',
    'per_latino',
    'per_same_h', 
    'per_same_c', 
    'per_diff_c'
]


# Fit OLS model
import itertools

pairs = list(itertools.combinations(range(crime_demograph[variable_names].shape[1]), 1))

vals_list = []

for pair in pairs:
    x_subset = crime_demograph[variable_names].values[:, pair]

# Fit OLS model
    m1 = spreg.OLS(
        # Dependent variable
        crime_demograph["kfr_pooled_pooled_p25"].values,
        # Independent variables
        x_subset,
        # Dependent variable name
        name_y="kfr_pooled_pooled_p25",
        # Independent variable name
        name_x= [variable_names[p] for p in pair]
    )
    
    #print(m1.summary)
    vals_list.append(m1.ar2)

#arrange models by adjusted r-squared and then put in new model.
```
````

I can then make a data frame with the variables and corresponding R^2 values and then sort from the largest explained variance to the smallest with this code:

````
```
adj_r_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'vars': variable_names, 
     'vals': vals_list}
)\
.sort_values('vals', ascending = False)

variable_names = adj_r_df['vars'].tolist()
```
````

Then I can input these variables into a regression model in that order:

````
```
  x_subset = crime_demograph[adj_r_df['vars']]

    spreg.OLS(
            # Dependent variable
        crime_demograph["kfr_pooled_pooled_p25"].values,
            # Independent variables
            x_subset.values,
            # Dependent variable name
            name_y="kfr_pooled_pooled_p25",
            # Independent variable name
            name_x= variable_names
    )
        
    ```
````

What I want to do is have model significance be assessed with each additional variable, and if that variable does not significantly reduce AIC, adjusted R^2, it is not included in the model and the next subsequent variable is tested. Does anyone know of such a package or how I could code this?

Here is data sample (first three rows):

````
```
crime_demograph = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'GEOID': {0: '06073000100', 1: '06073000201', 2: '06073000202'},
 'crime_count': {0: 26, 1: 39, 2: 90},
 'bus_count': {0: 22, 1: 31, 2: 54},
 'median_hh_': {0: 138879.0, 1: 88125.0, 2: 76658.0},
 'population': {0: 3093.0, 1: 1891.0, 2: 4542.0},
 'per_white': {0: 0.907856450048497,
  1: 0.877313590692755,
  2: 0.857551739321885},
 'per_black': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.005288207297726, 2: 0.000880669308675},
 'per_asian': {0: 0.039120594891691,
  1: 0.039661554732946,
  2: 0.083443416996918},
 'per_latino': {0: 0.158098933074685,
  1: 0.074034902168165,
  2: 0.135623073535887},
 'per_same_h': {0: 0.911841249186727,
  1: 0.881319850984566,
  2: 0.785303231518371},
 'per_same_c': {0: 0.060182173064411,
  1: 0.05747738158595,
  2: 0.156485170429394},
 'per_diff_c': {0: 0.009759271307742,
  1: 0.011708355508249,
  2: 0.007746790615317},
 'kfr_pooled_pooled_p25': {0: 0.45727569, 1: 0.51709598, 2: 0.45559084}}
)
```
````